# ssh -X gives an error

Tags: ssh, opengl

Problem is I have installed Virtual Nanolab software. It works fine on local machine but when I tried `ssh -Y` forward the software. I get error

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

with white small box

I am using MacBook.

`xclock` or other gnome-software-center app works fine on `ssh -Y` in MacBook.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, software that requires 3D acceleration doesn't through a piped ssh.

Comment: so how can I get this 3D acceleration ? is it any ways I can do it through ssh

Comment: The only way is installing an X server on the server side with hardware acceleration and then using VNC or x2go.